# in python, How can I make 'ascii' codec understand codes like u'\u2014' , u'\u2019' etc

Tags: python, pandas, ascii, dataframe

By python I have read some xml data and put them into a pandas.DataFrame now I want to write them in a file by `df.to_csv(...)` but it gives me this error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 1257: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I make 'ascii' codec understand codes like `u'\u2014'`, `u'\u2019'` etc

Comment: You can't. ASCII cannot handle anything beyond `\u007f`. You'd pick a different encoding instead.

Comment: The alternative is to use [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) to replace non-ASCII codepoints with reasonable ASCII equivalents and surrogates. U+2014 is EM-DASH, which can reasonably be substituted with a doubled plain `-` dash, for example. Ditto for U+2019, which is a fancy single quote, `'` could replace it. That library does this.

Comment: You can use `encoding` argument in `to_csv()` : string, optional
        a string representing the encoding to use if the contents are
        non-ascii, for python versions prior to 3

Comment: Thanks a lot indeed. it worked, it just added some ] or [ to the text